# Calling methods with parameters inside other methods

Tags: c#, methods, parameters

I have this two methods that in the first look are fine.

But the problem is that e parameter of `RadWizard2_NextButtonClick` method is returning the value of e parameter of `radTxb_TextChanged` method.

I tried to change the name of `e` parameter in one of the methods but than returns me `null` all the time when in fact it should not.

Any idea why this is happening or where i am doing wrong??

```
protected void radTxb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    //dothings
    if (!opMsg.IsError)
    {
        RadWizard2_NextButtonClick(sender, e as WizardEventArgs); // arguments WITHOUT types    
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the actual error message?

Comment: How does a `void` return anything? Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: @Saruman this is the exception i am getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" and it comes from e parameter returning null since is not getting the value from WizardEventArgs

Comment: @oerkelens is not getting the value from WizardEventArg so is returning null. why and how i have no idea why. thats why i am asking for your help

Comment: You mean that casting `EventArgs` to `WizardEventArgs` results in `null`. That has been explained already.

Comment: What do you want your code to achieve? Do actually want to call your custom event handler code in radTxb_TextChanged or (my guess) do you want to simulate a click on the next wizard button if the radTxb text has been changed? If the latter, you are on the wrong track.

Comment: The `as` operator returns a non-null value only if the object actually _is_ the type you are trying to cast to. It's not going to convert arbitrary objects to your desired type. Passing `null` would be fine as long as the method in question doesn't want to use the object, but that appears not to be the case. Unfortunately, you have not provided enough detail for anyone to know what _would_ work in your scenario. Fix your question so it includes a good [mcve] and details as to what you want the code to do, why you think that's reasonable, and what _specifically_ you need help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to *create* `WizardEventArgs` instance, e.g.:

```
 protected void radTxb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
   if (!opMsg.IsError) {
     // It seems you have to provide some parameters:
     // currentIndex and nextIndex which
     RadWizard2_NextButtonClick(sender, 
                                new WizardEventArgs(currentIndex, nextIndex)); 
   }
 }
```

If you inspect `e` instance, you'll find it of `EventArgs` type; and sice `EventArgs` has not been inherited from `WizardEventArgs` (quite the opposite is true: it is `WizardEventArgs` which is derived from `EventArgs`)

```
  e as WizardEventArgs
```

returns `null` (`e` being `EventArgs` instabce can't be treated as `WizardEventArgs` instance)

Comment: your code is giving me this error 'Telerik.Web.UI.WizardEventArgs' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Comment: @Lara then look at the hint your editor gives you. It will probably tell you which constructors there _are_ and what you should pass to them.

Comment: @Lara: It seems that you should provide two arguments: `currentIndex` and `nextIndex` parameters; what are these indexes' value depend on your program logic

Comment: @DmitryBychenko from WizardEventArgs Class                     namespace Telerik.Web.UI
{
    public class WizardEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public WizardEventArgs(RadWizardStep currentStep, RadWizardStep nextStep);

        public RadWizardStep CurrentStep { get; set; }
        public int CurrentStepIndex { get; set; }
        public RadWizardStep NextStep { get; set; }
        public int NextStepIndex { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: @Lara: please, notice *constructor's* declaration `public WizardEventArgs(RadWizardStep currentStep, RadWizardStep nextStep);`. So if we want to create `WizardEventArgs` instance we have to provide `currentStep` and `nextStep` parameters

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Hi again. I am trying to create the new Instance but gives me this error for the nextStep parameter.The name 'nextStep' does not exist in the current context. I created it like this WizardEventArgs Event = new WizardEventArgs(currentStep, nextStep);  Any idea why? should i add smth more?Should i create it in a specific place? Thank you

Comment: @Lara: `nextStep` is out of scope. Where have you declared `nextStep`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenkon the thing is that when i declare nextStep where the currentStep is declared also all the row is marks as an error and i get erros like.  The best overloaded method match for 'Telerik.Web.UI.WizardEventArgs.WizardEventArgs(Telerik.Web.UI.RadWizardStep, Telerik.Web.UI.RadWizardStep)' has some invalid arguments  and cannot convert from 'int' to 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadWizardStep' when in fact currentStep was already declared as private int

Comment: @Lara: then you have to declare and create RadWizardStep instances, not int ones

Answer (score 0):

I know i'm late to the party, however you might be able to just get away with `null`

```
protected void radTxb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    //dothings
    if (!opMsg.IsError)
    {
        RadWizard2_NextButtonClick(sender, null); // arguments WITHOUT types    
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i can but the thing is i dont want e to be null i want it to return something from WizardEventArgs

Comment: @Lara you need to work with Dmitry Bychenko answer in that case

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest a different approach.

You are trying to call a UI event handler *directly*. This is almost always a bad idea. Event handlers are designed to handle events, not to be used as library methods.

If you need the code from `RadWizard2_NextButtonClick` in your `radTxb_TextChanged` method, just extract it into a new method:

Before:

```
protected void RadWizard2_NextButtonClick(object sender, WizardEventArgs e)
{
    ... // some code here
}
```

After:

```
protected void RadWizard2_NextButtonClick(object sender, WizardEventArgs e)
{
    DoStuff();
}

private void DoStuff()
{
    ... // some code here
}
```

You can now call `DoStuff` in your `radTxb_TextChanged` method.

Comment: i think i understand your aproach but the thing is that (i am using your exe) i need firstly to go through DoStuff method than check the other. To be clear, i have a barcodeReader to scan items. I scan go through DoStuf method,if the item is found than go for RadWizard2_NextButtonClick (method for going in the second step) etc

Comment: @Lara: This is were you are mistaken: RadWizard2_NextButtonClick is *NOT* the method for going int the second step. RadWizard2_NextButtonClick is an event handler allowing you to add custom code which is executed when going to the second step.

Comment: @Lara: To go to the next step, you need to do something like: `RadWizard2.SelectedPageIndex = ...;` (check the RadWizard documentation for details, I have never used it myself).

Comment: but how will be possible than to check for the Barcode that is supposed to be done in the DoStuff  if i firstly enter in the RadWizard2_NextButtonClick method?

Answer (score 0):

When you need to do something, write a method that does exactly what you need. Give it a name that describes what it does, and give it only the arguments that it needs. Then you can call that method from event handlers or anywhere else. You can also put the method in a separate class so you can reuse it if needed across pages and keep the code-behind from getting too big.

It's peculiar that the built-in event handlers often contain vague arguments that aren't even used and aren't cast as the correct type, such as:

```
protected void radTxb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Obviously the sender isn't going to be any object. It's going to be a specific type of control. And the event args are also going to be of a particular type. The way they are cast implies that they don't matter, and in many cases they won't even be used. We know what happened just because the method fired, and we respond to that and ignore the arguments.

But we don't need to follow that convention. We can just write our methods according to their own requirements. If you want to do something with a `RadWizard` after an event has fired, you can just write the method you want:

```
public void DoSomethingWithTheRadWizard(RadWizard radWizard)
```

In the event handlers, extract whatever values you need from the arguments and then call your more specific method. It will be much easier to read and understand when all of the arguments are used and each is declared as the correct type.